# reset /clear button?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

hi im using visual studio 2010 and asp

i just created simple form with submit and clear button
and i want to clear all textboxes

the sumbit button is working. but idk for clear button.

note:
the button1_click is subit button,
button2_click is clear button

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsPostBack)


            Response.Write("Success");
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       ////////  -- i dont know what to put here huhuhu help

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have text boxes called Text1, Text2, Text3 (etc.) -->

```
<asp:textbox id="Text1" runat="server" />
<asp:textbox id="Text2" runat="server" />
<asp:textbox id="Text3" runat="server" />
```

then to clear the entry in the text boxes server side, you want to have the following code in the Button2_click() method (assumed to be the Clear button) -->

```
Text1.Text = "";
Text2.Text = "";
Text3.Text = "";
```

Comment: thank it works! however it wont click because my form has required validation how can i ignore that

Comment: use CausesValidation="false" in the ASPX declaration of Button2, which should be something like --> <asp:button id="Button2" runat="server" text="Clear" CausesValidation="false" />

Comment: (this is real basic ASPX btw)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the ID of the textboxes are `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`, here's how it's done:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

**EDIT**
To avoid the required validation when `Button2` is clicked, first set the `ValidationGroup` property of the `RequiredFieldValidator` to any non empty value, let's say `Submit`:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rq1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Submit" />
```

then the submit button must have the same value for its `ValidationGroup` property so it will validate the textboxes when it's clicked:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Submit" />
```

finally do not set the `ValidationGroup` property of the clear button so it will ignore the validation defined in `rq1` when it's clicked:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" />
```

For more information regarding `ValidationGroup`, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: thank it works! however it wont click because my form has required validation? how can i ignore that? thanks